# Diodes used with MOV, which ones and why?

Tags: power, diodes, dc, mov

i was hoping to get some help identifying a component on an old circuit board that i have to repair, id also like to undertand the purpose of this combination of components.[image]

The circuit is on an industrial plasma cutter from 1988 , this circuit runs at about 250-300v dc @ 40-80 Amps, it runs between the 3 phase rectifiers and the ssr

in short the 3phase supply goes through the transformer, into the recitiers on the  left edge of the photo, it then passes through this circuit and goes into the ssr on the top edge of the photo, the full voltage is 300v 80 amp dc, drops to around 250v under load, as this is an inductive load from the transformer, and is being switched by pwm controlled ssr, and it this circuit mostly consists of mov's i assume its purpose will be to prevent transient voltage spikes from switching under load, what i dont know is what type or rating these diodes are.
could someone assist me with identifying them and tell me what specs i should be replacing them with?

Comment: Without a **schematic** we can only **guess** what is going on here. As this is high voltage **and** high current, no sane engineer would **guess** what is going on here. A sane engineer wants a full schematic including the parts on other boards that are connected to this board.

Comment: a fair point, unfortunately schematics are not available, i will add a second picture that will give more context,  and ill edit for a better description.

Comment: *unfortunately schematics are not available,* Then you have no option but to **reverse engineer** (trace out) the schematic.